# Appropriate database design for sparse user profiles

Tags: mongodb, database-design, hbase, impala, database

I'd like to efficiently store and query user data. A user is identified by a unique UUID, and can have values for hundreds of different attributes (all boolean, numeric or string). However, for most users, the number of known attributes is very limited, so most values are null. Moreover, some attributes are hierarchical in nature (eg female (yes-no) --> likes_heels (yes-no) --> likes_red_heels (yes-no)). There are 100 million different users, and new possible attributes get added frequently.

I'm considering 3 options : a relational table-structure (eg Impala), key-value storage (eg HBase) and a JSON-based database (eg MongoDB).

The focus is currently on performing queries (eg how many users are male, over 30-years-old and Chinese ?)

I look forward to your recommendations !

Answer (score 1):

I can share my experience with similar use case. We used HBase to store thousands of such attributes. Please note that in our case, attribute value were always true/false/null. Null meant we could not decisively tell whether it is false or true.

The goals were to

- To run large scale aggregation for a complex boolean expression. For example, give me aggregates (counts) for all users that are female and also who like heels between 2 dates.
- Allow to run above aggregation for a sample because in most of the cases, sample gave us fair indication of trends (very quickly)
- Ability to add attributes
- Minimize storage and hence scan times

We encoded all attributes into a bitmap data structure. Every attribute had a unique offset value (position in a bitmap). If a bit is set, the user is a female or like heels. To handle null, we stored an additional bit map for every user. If a bit is false in first bitmap then we checked the same position in 2nd bitmap to see if it is true. We treated that to be null if 2nd bitmap had the bit set.

BitMap on its own reduced the footprint by an order of magnitude. You can also use Sparse bit map structure like Roaring Bit Maps to reduce storage and increasing the efficiency.

Looking up a bit in a bitmap (byte array) is a constant time operation. We then used HBase Co-processors to perform aggregations. The client would pass the boolean expression like

```
att1 && att2 && (att3 || att4)
```

The client would also pass the offsets for each of the attributes in the expression. This enabled the co-processor to scan the bits for filtered rows based on offsets.

Our row key design was based on SHA1 of the user id. It was

```
<FIRST 2 BYTES of SHA1><DD-MM-YYYY><40 bytes of SHA1>
```

This allowed us to use HBase's Fuzzy row filters to

- Scan a sample out of possible 256 shards (first 2 bytes)
- Scan for date range

I have tested this approach for about 6000 attributes without sparse bitmap and for about 15000 attributes with sparse bitmaps. In some cases, it is possible to model the numeric attributes in bitmaps (obviously not continuous values).

We were looking to handle 4-5 billion users and with each user being modeled about 3 times (average), thus storing about 15 billion such events (userid - date - modeled attribute set). We also supported feature to perform distinct counts since same user could have attributes modeled differently in different dates.

We performed all encodings in Map/Reduce and use HBase bulk load feature to perform extremely fast loads.

One of the pluses of this design is that since we kept a copy of all encoded data in HDFS, we could have written a custom Hive/Impala/Spark UDF to perform filter/evaluation for querying via SQL. Also the copy in HDFS can be kept for longer time (longer than it can be kept in HBase) as cold layer.

We also considered Apache Phoenix but we did not choose that as we wanted to support aggregations on 100s of expressions at the same time instead of one expression at a time.

I hope this helps.